Merge request with submodules in Gitlab?
When a merge request in main repo contains a new pointer in a submodule we have to manually merge these MR's and review the changes in submodule locally.
Maybe there is any way to make it more convinient? At least some way to review submodule changes  inside web Gitlab? Maybe some subrequests or smth.
